# customizing a scrolling script for iphone using (iscroll)

Tags: javascript, iphone

I’m trying to use a premade script for a calendar function on our website. 
The script is from:
http://cubiq.org/iscroll/
I’m really really new, so I’m really sorry if this is really newbie.. but is there any way for the script to snap to each list item, when scrolling?

Thanks a lot!!

S

Comment: (a preview of the page is up on http://sodasoda.net/test/cal )

Answer (score 1):

If you just need a calendar like that, cubiq offers a separate plugin: http://cubiq.org/spinning-wheel-on-webkit-for-iphone-ipod-touch